# STM32CubeProgrammer - Segmentation fault (SIGSEGV) when trying to connect to a STM32MP157F-DK2 board via SWD/JTAG

Tags: stm32

When I try to connect to a `STM32MP157F-DK2` board via `SWD/JTAG`, `STM32CubeProgrammer` aborts with a segmentation fault on my host system (openSUSE Leap 15.2).

I get the following error message, when I start `STM32CubeProgrammer` within a shell:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fee0c8259fe, pid=14499, tid=0x00007fee00ee6700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_265-b01) (build 1.8.0_265-b01)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.265-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libCubeProgrammer_API.so+0x5b9fe]  connectStLink+0x2ee
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /usr/local/STMicroelectronics/STM32Cube/STM32CubeProgrammer/bin/core or core.14499
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /usr/local/STMicroelectronics/STM32Cube/STM32CubeProgrammer/bin/hs_err_pid14499.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
./STM32CubeProgrammer: line 4: 14499 Aborted                 (core dumped) $DIR/jre/bin/java -Djdk.gtk.version=2 -jar $DIR/STM32CubeProgrammerLauncher
```

I also own a `NUCLEO-H745ZI-Q` board, but no issues with `STM32CubeProgrammer` with this target board.

Has somebody noticed the same issue?

I use the latest version 2.9.0.

**UPDATE:**
I also asked this on the [ST Community site](https://community.st.com). An ST employee has created an internal support ticket for this issue. You can read this in my selected answer at my [question](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00001Nw4j6SAB/stm32cubeprogrammer-segmentation-fault-sigsegv-when-trying-to-connect-to-a-stm32mp157fdk2-via-swdjtag). It also affects when an user use Ubuntu as host system. Verified from an other customer.

Comment: This is a tool bug. You should report it. You can try installing Oracle JRE instead of OpenJDK and see if it helps.